# Is there a way to add object attribute?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to find a working solution to type-hinting a new attribute was added to a generic object.

A simple example:

```py
def annotate_attribute(objs: list):
    for obj in objs:
        obj.some_attribute = "something"
    return objs
```

I've tried the following code:

```py
class WithAnnotation[T](type[T]):
    some_attribute: str


def annotate_attribute[T](objs: list[T]) -> list[WithAnnotation[T]]:
    for obj in objs:
        obj.some_attribute = "something"
    return objs
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick, as PyCharm only gives me suggestions for `WithAnnotation`, but not the underlying object (see screenshot).
[image]

Is there a way to do it? Or is there some other way to solve my problem, without this "magic" annotation?

I'm using Python 3.12 and I use PyCharm 2023.3 to check the types.

Comment: This is called *intersection typing*. In Typescript, it would simply be `T & {some_attribute: str}`. Python's type hinting does not support intersection typing, though it has [been](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/18) [proposed](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) a few times.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate, but I suspected it. Thanks a lot!